# Make time stamp from string

Tags: ruby, time

I need to format `161901` to `04:19:01PM`.

I tried the following:

```
Time.parse(161901)
```

```
"161901".chars.each_slice(2).map(&:join)
```

```
Time.parse("161901".chars.each_slice(2).map(&:join))
```

Being a newbie to ruby, it is difficult to find a way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's is the most basic answer, but it makes some assumptions:

```ruby
require 'time'

time = Time.strptime('161901', '%H%M%S')
time.strftime('%I:%M:%S%p')

=> "04:19:01PM"
```

The issue is that your string '161901' may or may not be padded and it might also be an integer and not a string. For example, if the time was 6:00 am, perhaps you get a string such as: '60000', you would need to pad this on the left hand side to parse this properly. Due to this I would suggest the following approach:

```ruby
require 'time'

# Assume your time is an integer with no right padding:
time = 61901
ptime = Time.strptime(time.to_s.rjust(6, '0'), '%H%M%S') # Do proper padding
ptime.strftime('%I:%M:%S%p')

=> "06:19:00AM"
```

This should help sanitize your variable that you are parsing to produce consistent results.

References: https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html#method-i-strftime

Comment: Good point about the possible need for padding.

Answer (score 3):

[DateTime::strptime](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.7.0/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html#method-c-strptime) and [DateTime#strftime](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.7.0/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html#method-i-strftime) are purpose-built for this task.

```
require 'time'
```

```
fmt_in  = '%H%M%S'
fmt_out = '%I:%M:%S%p'
```

```
t = DateTime.strptime('161901', fmt_in)
t.strftime(fmt_out)
  #=> "04:19:01PM
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do like below it was very easy for use multiple times with environment variables if you have fixed display format for time

```
require 'time'

class Time
  def self.strpftime(str, in_format,
                     out_format = ENV.fetch('out_format'))
    strptime(str, in_format).strftime(out_format)
  end
end
# with out using environment variable  
Time.strpftime('161901', '%H%M%S', '%I:%M:%S%p')
=> "04:19:01PM"

# using environment variable
Time.strpftime('161901', '%H%M%S')
=> "04:19:01PM"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
require 'time'

input = '161901'
formatted_input = input.split('').each_slice(2).to_a.map(&:join).join(':')
time = Time.parse(formatted_time)
formatted_time = time.strftime("%I:%M:%S%p")
```

Output:

```
=> "04:19:01PM"
```

Comment: `input` should be `time` or `time` should be `input`. Additionally 1) `time.split('')` can be `time.each_char` to avoid the unnecessary `Array` creation. 2)  the `to_a` is not necessary as `map` is an `Enumerable` method this will avoid another unnecessary `Array` creation

Answer (score 0):

You'll be best off using "strptime" when converting strings to dates or times.

https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.1/libdoc/time/rdoc/Time.html#method-c-strptime :

```
2.5.8 :006 > Time.strptime("161901","%H%M%S")
 => 2020-12-18 16:19:01 +0000
```

this will get you a "Time" object that you'll be able to query, parse, sort and/or output in different format.